# Business Process Automation in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have development experience of SharePoint 2010 and never used OOTB workflows as I have been using Nintex for so long. Now I have one requirement in which I have to work with SP 2013 and OOTB. All the workflows will be state machine and there has to be a delegation of approval option.

Is it possible to develop such comprehensive workflows (OOTB) in SP 2013?

Would appreciate any links to gain knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 does come with a (2010) approval workflow out of the box that is done through the front-end. Not much customization available for it, but it's available in a minutes.

SharePoint Designer will allow you to create an approval workflow, though it is not technically a state machine. It does get the job done and is relatively easy to set up/maintain.

MS Visual Studio will allow you to develop a state machine with an approval workflow through a variety of possible implementations. While this path does involve packaging and deploying as a solution, it doesn't involve much unless you want it to. There are a few different bits of publicly available code written for 2013 and 2010 that you can Google ('SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio approval workflow') and download. 2010 solutions can either be upgraded in VS or adapted.

If you need real customization, you can tie the Visual Studio approach together with event receivers.